# IIS takes up to 2 minutes to handle off and request to .NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We have an .NET application hosted on IIS, it has 4 GET/POST methods.

What i found that under higher load (100 parallel calls), it takes IIS about 2 minutes between when the GET/POST request is received and when the .NET Application starts to handle it.

This happened on a local test server, still happens after app was deployed to azure with more powerfull CPU/RAM.

I am currently looking into any possible limits like number of connections but making no progress.

Anyone can offer any hints?

Thank you

**Additional info based on questions asked:**

Overall, until the number of parallel clients reaches 50, it works as expected. After this grows over 50 (this is not a hard number, moves between about 50-60 clients), we start to see this issue with IIS not handling over the request to .NET fast enough.

After a second IIS server was deployed and the .NET application was installed, it is now capable of serving 100 users, ergo 50 users / IIS.

Comment: What IIS configuration are you using? Have you tried increasting the number of worker processes for the application pool and seeing if this makes any difference?
What happens to the timings from 1-100, I'm assuming it doesn't just jump from acceptable performance to 2 minutes?

Comment: Im not really an IIS guy, i got this dumped on me cos i am available and i am considered to be good in branching out into different parts of the system. Read: As far as IIS is considered, i am a newbie. More info added to question

Comment: You should also be looking at what you are hosting within IIS. Specifically, what you logic does in terms of end-to-end. IIS can handle parallel request but the processing those parallel request is your responsibility. So you will be better off checking your implementation details on how you handle the request.

Comment: @Nair: Yes, I will have to look into that, however, i still feel while that may be a bottlenect, the issue is really the delay between IIS receiving the request and the corresponding methond being called.

To explain:
1st) a Post method is called
2nd) a Get method is called
3rd) a Post method is called
4rd) a Get method is called
After the post methods are handled, there is a timelimit of 60seconds for the Get method to be called. The applications all log this to be true, yet the delay between IIS and .NET app causes it to fall

Comment: If you don't know IIS good enough, you should grab such a guy nearby or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com. You should not expect anyone on SO can magically see your server and code. One hint you might use right now, is to study failed request tracing feature and use it to track further where the time goes. That kind of detail can tell which module of IIS is the culprit and more actions can be taken.

Comment: check your application flow and functionalities.. you said it is .net application.. i think you must check it..

Comment: Maybe IIS is waiting for threads to become available?  If the .Net web methods are made async this will help free up those threads to service other requests while waiting for the response.

Comment: Use IIS Request Tracing and set it to 200-600 as StatusCodes, then you might see what takes long.

Comment: Which enviroment are you running the app in? Windows Server 2012? Is the CPU and or RAM maxxed?